# styling mysql connect page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

does anybody know how to style the 'echo' tags on my page? i am pulling from a mysql table, but cannot figure out how to style the individual rows. any help would be appreciated. here is my code:

```
 <?
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","ameriex9_eric","fitness2003","ameriex9_blog");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM blog_entries ORDER BY date DESC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  echo $row['name'];
  echo "<br>" ;
  echo $row['date'] ;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $row['title']; 
  echo "<br>"; 
  echo $row['blog'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo $row['pics'];
  echo "<hr>";
}
  mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: now change your password

Comment: dont worry, its just localhost :)

Comment: just for argument ;) stack overflow folks would easily login if this question was posted from a static ip.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the individual rows like this, for example:

```
echo "<span class=\"myclass\">{$row['name']}</span>";
```

where `.myClass` can be a class somewhere in your CSS file.

This would work too:

```
echo '<span class="myClass">Name' . $row['name'] . '</span><br>';
```

Inline styles is possible too, though being more messier:

```
echo '<span style="color:red; font-size:12px;">Name' . $row['name'] . '</span><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add a small style rule

```
<style scoped>
table,td{ border:1px solid #f4f4f4; border-collapse:collapse; padding:10px; }
</style>
```

and slightly modify your code around while loop like this...

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['date']."</td><td>".$row['blog']."</td><td>".$row['pics']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: it was just put as a temporary placement. I insist that the users would put that style in their `<head>`